# How to check if user is logged in or not in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am using the custom login and logout in Laravel. Now I want to check through  middleware if the user is authenticated and then they will pass through, otherwise they will be redirected back to the login page. So far I tried this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (! Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

It is not working because when I `dd(Auth::check())`, it gives me false as output. Please help me to solve this problem.
This is my login code

```
$email=Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->login, 'password' => $request->password]);
        $username=Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->login, 'password' => $request->password]);
        if($username || $email)
        {
            $activity=new Activity;
            $activity->user_id=Auth::id();
            $activity->login_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $activity->save();
            return redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return back()->with('msg', 'Error!Enter Cedentials Correctly');
        }
```

Comment: what is custom login and logout?

Comment: means not default login and logout which is provided by laravel

Comment: show the code for that

Comment: login code was added

Comment: did you use yung `middleware` in your `route` file. `Route::middleware('auth')->get('/', function() { return view('welcom')})`. If you are inserting new `class` on your `middleware` folder you should bring it in the `kernel`

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware needs to run after the web middleware because the web middleware is responsible for booting up the session.

Also, I'm not entirely sure you can use the middleware method in your controller for middleware groups. You might be able to, but I've never actually tried that. If I were you though, I'd follow the default structure and just put the routes inside a web route group.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Laravel Auth then i think this should work for you.

```
if (\Auth::user()->id !== null) {
    return redirect('/');
}

return $next($request);
```